# Is it possible to use Cocoa Touch gesture recognizers with layers / CALayer objects?

Tags: cocoa-touch, calayer, ios

Is it possible to use gesture recognizers with layers? Let's say I want to add several sublayers to my view and implement drag&drop as well as tapping on single element.
Is it possible at all ? What is the best pattern?

Answer (score 8):

You could try adding gesturerecognizers to your `UIView` and then call

```
- (CALayer *)hitTest:(CGPoint)thePoint
```

on your view's layer to find which layer you hit, eg;

```
CALayer* layerThatWasTapped = [gestureView.layer hitTest:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:gestureView]];
```