# Detect touches on sublayer elements

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uicontrol, cashapelayer

I have MyCustomView view as subclass of the UIControl class.
I draw stuff on my view like this:

```
   CAShapeLayer *line = [CAShapeLayer layer];
   ....
   [self.layer addSublayer:line];
```

Is it anyway to detect touches on 'line' and do some work? For example move 'line'.

Comment: Check here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469211/is-it-possible-to-use-cocoa-touch-gesture-recognizers-with-layers-calayer-obje

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding gesturerecognizers to your UIView and then call

```
  - (CALayer *)hitTest:(CGPoint)thePoint
```

on your view's layer to find which layer you hit, eg;

```
   CALayer* layerThatWasTapped = [line.layer hitTest:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:line]];
```